# Creating calculator in abap

Tags: algorithm, abap

I've build a basic calculator in abap which is pretty simple and knows how to get 2 inputs and calculate them by pressing a push button of the operator( + - / *).
Now I want to make a calculator which gets one input like : "12+5*3-9"
But I really don't know how to start it.
Can anyone help me a little bit please?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You question is related with an algorithm for parsing mathematical strings rather than ABAP. One of them is [Shunting-yard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shunting-yard_algorithm).

If you need to short way, you can add your expression into java script function and run it in CL_JAVA_SCRIPT class in ABAP.

Check example ABAP program DEMO_JAVA_SCRIPT_MINI_EDITOR.

Comment: Nice answer, but why Javascript, is there a script ready-to-use? A parser is very easy to implement in all languages. About [CL_JAVA_SCRIPT](https://help.sap.com/http.svc/rc/abapdocu_752_index_htm/7.52/en-US/index.htm?file=abennews-610-javascript.htm): "support for the connection of JavaScript to ABAP will be discontinued without replacement in a Release after 7.02" (I don't know what it means exactly)

Comment: @SandraRossi sometimes we need very complex user defined expressions (sin, cos, pi, square, etc). Running complex expression in another language generally easy. I don't new another script language for ABAP using like this. Also we can dynamically create ABAP codes like this [blog](http://letscodeabap.blogspot.com/2015/03/dynamic-code-generation-in-abap.html). May be we need extra authorization doing this.

Comment: that's not what is asked - currently it's only for simple formulas. Anyway, mathematical functions are not complex to implement too, even in ABAP. Why dynamic abap?